# Jquery Datepicker looses format

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help with this jquery, It is designed to not allow any user to select a date less than the start date, which works OK, but I cannot get it to use UK date format or prevent a date in the past from been selected, If I remove everything except the date format the format works as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CheckIn").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#CheckOut").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
            $("#CheckOut").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);

        }
    });
    $("#CheckOut").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#CheckIn").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
            $("#CheckIn").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);

        }
    });
});
```

This works on its own

```
$("#CheckIn").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
```

can anyone see where I'm going wrong

Forgot to mention this is code I'm using to stop people selecting day in past, but does not work

```
$("#Checkin").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

Thanks

======================Working Code ===========================

Code below also includes preventing users from selecting day in past.
Thanks to Jens Ahlsten Herlevsen and Palash Mondal for helping.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CheckIn").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: 0, //<<< Prevent day in past been selected
        onClose: function (selected) {
            $("#CheckOut").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);

        }
    });
    $("#CheckOut").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onClose: function (selected) {
            $("#CheckIn").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("#CheckIn").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();`
 re initiates the datepicker, i would suggest using just `$("#CheckIn").val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#CheckIn").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onClose: function (selected) {
        $("#CheckOut").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);

    }
});
$("#CheckOut").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onClose: function (selected) {
        $("#CheckIn").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);

    }
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qJcXh/

Comment: sorry cannot award answer to both

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$("#CheckIn").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var date = $("#CheckOut").val();
        $("#CheckOut").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
    }
});
$("#CheckOut").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var date = $("#CheckIn").val();
        $("#CheckIn").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);
    }
});
```